# Give permission only to certain software to access a folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-permissions

I have some confidential files that I create in MS Office. Now, I want only MS Office to have access to the folder where I save these files. Is it possible in windows 10 pro? I do not want other applications and softwares to have read and write access to this folder. Is it possible in Windows 10 Pro? In not much familiar with admin stuff. Any pointers will be very helpful.

Comment: “Is it possible in Windows 10 Pro?” - No

Comment: You could set security for that folder so that it's only available to you, but as far as adding a security object name for the application that created it, as @Ramhound said, nope.

Comment: Is this why ransomware are able to hijack files? Looks like windows has no inherent file security against malicious processes.